# Neo4j legacy index search with multiple values on a single field

Tags: java, neo4j, lucene

I have neo4j instance with a legacy lucene index on a particular property. Is it possible to run a search with multiple values on this property and return all the matched nodes? I am looking for something that like [that].[1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24053031/1613860)

I am using Neo4j 2.3.1 and that Java API.

Answer (score 0):

Neo4j legacy indexes support full lucene query syntax, http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/javadocs/org/neo4j/graphdb/index/ReadableIndex.html#query(java.lang.Object).

So the answer to your question is yes.